# RFID vs. Bluetooth vs. Wifi beacon

Tags: electrical-engineering, design, wifi

I want to build a small device (beacon) that can send its location (*inside* of a building) and can receive signals in order to output information on an LED screen. The beacon should communicate with a central unit.
So the device would be pretty similar to a [Tile](https://www.thetileapp.com/) in many ways.

Here's a picture to illustrate the problem:

[image]
The beacon is currently located in area 1. When pinged, it should either send back its exact coordinates (so that the central unit can calculate that the beacon is positioned in area 1) or the current area id.
Once the beacon is moved, it should of course update its position.
The areas are inside of a building, always rectangular and I can install hardware on site (e.g. on the four emitters in the corners of the rectangles). The side length of the areas is between 1 and 20 meters.

Right now, I am evaluating different possible technologies. The biggest challenge is that I need 2-way communication.

Other requirements:

- The beacon should have a battery life of several *months*
- The beacon should update its location on a regular basis (e.g. once a minute) and on demand (when triggered from the central unit)
- There can be up to 5,000 beacons in one area at a time. They all have to work simultaneously

**RFID**
+ Passive (no need for batteries)
+ Cheap
+ Location detection should be fairly easy with "gates"
- Range probably too short for my scenario
- No 2-way communication possible (would need additional module)

**Bluetooth**
+ Battery life with low energy BT
+ Range should suffice
+ 2-way communication possible
- Not sure how many BT beacons can be connected to the central unit at once (probably not 5,000)
- Not sure how locating the beacon would work (signal strength?)

**Wifi**
+ Range
+ 2-way communication
+ Connection to thousands of beacons at the same time possible
- Not wure how locating the beacon would work (signal strength?)
- Battery life?

I highly appreciate any recommendations, tips and improvements. Right now, I don't really know which way to take and it would end in a lot of trial and error :)

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts on your options:

**RFID**, as you stated, likely won't work, most certainly not over 20 meters as low power devices, that's not what it is designed for.

**Bluetooth** and **WiFi** would work with signal strength measurement (proximity) and triangulation. The signal strength measurement could lack the desired accuracy, especially if you're in the 1m range. But if accuracy isn't very important, you probably should choose one of those.

As an alternative, I once worked with [these RF Modules](http://www.decawave.com/products/dwm1000-module) (low-power, good range, good precision), but 5'000 connections are not possible (if I remember it correctly). Maybe there are other solutions in this direction..

Anyway, sounds like an interesting project. (What do you need 5'000 beacons for?)

Comment: Thanks - the RF modules seem interesting. The project is to keep track of moving parts in manufacturing.